# Ты что () глухонемой?

Tags: пунктуация

*Ты что () глухонемой? Тебя что () дома не кормят?* **Нужны ли в этих и им подобных вопросительных предложениях какие-то знаки пунктуации после "что"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь "что" выступает в роли частицы. Важно что здесь это "что" не выступает в роли знаменательного члена предложения или союза. В таком случае это частица, обычно модальная. В сочетании с личным местоимением пунктуация всегда именно такая. ***"Тебя что, не кормили?", "А я что, рыжий?"*** и т. п.

> Частица что - одна или в сочетании с другими простыми частицами -
>   может вносить значения вопроса (Что, устал?); осуждающего поиска
>   причины, основания (Что это ты сегодня ни минутки на месте не
>   посидишь!); несущественности и отстранимости (Что деньги! Ему выговор
>   что! А вы здесь должны решать, а не на общем собрании. Им что поднять
>   руку! Макар.); протеста, возражения ( - Заснете и не услышите. - Что
>   это заснем! разг. речь).

http://rusgram.narod.ru/1689-1705.html
§ 1695

Но тут надо быть внимательным, В других случаях, та же частица, тем более - являющаяся членом предложения, требует и иной пунктуации
Примеры есть даже в словаре.
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE&all=x

Не совсем ясно какая должна быть пунктуация в случае, если в примерах, пробных исходным, стоит не личное местоимение. "Собак(,) что, не кормили?" - убедительных примеров не нашел, а запятую перед "что" поставить почему-то хочется. Здесь тоже частица, но какая-то "вводная". Если кто-то найдет опровержение или, тем более, подтверждение - буду весьма признателен.

Comment: А не могли бы вы добавить цитату, где указывается на модальность частицы?

Comment: @Aer да там же и указывается, по ссылке. Весь параграф, откуда цитата взята  - § 1695 про "модальные частицы..."

Comment: а, ну вот вы добавили, спасибо. А кто автор грамматики этой? Шведова?

Comment: Это академическая грамматика "АГ-80", коллективный труд. Обычно на неё так и ссылаются. Вопросов не вызывает. Но вообще - под редакцией Виноградова, Бархударова, Истриной и еще кучи народа.

Comment: Виноградов какой?) Виктор Владимирович что ли? Есть грамматика 80-го  года, я -- и не только -- привык называть ее грамматикой **Шведовой** (в отличие как раз от грамматики **Виноградова**). Но это так, "терминология".

Comment: Так о ней и речь. АГ-80. У Шведовой грамматика ***не*** академическая (по названию).

Answer (score 2):

*Что* может выступать в значении вопросительной частицы в начале вопросительного предложения. В таких случаях эта частица употребляется для усиления вопроса.

> *[Дарья Ивановна:] Что, у вас такой же прекрасный голос?* Тургенев, Провинциалка. *— Что, бедняга, тебя обижают? — говорит второкурсник
>   ласково.* Помяловский, Очерки бурсы. *— Что, ему лет двадцать пять, не
>   больше?* Л. Толстой, Два гусара.

**Частица отделяется от основного предложения запятой**: *Ты что, глухонемой?; Тебя что, дома не кормят?*

*(Сведения взяты из "Малого академического словаря" А. П. Евгеньевой.)*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52385/discussion-on-answer-by-aer---).